# How to allow a related model in Yii to be empty

Tags: yii

In my Yii application I have a pretty simple model setup. I've used the gii autogenerated code to create the basic CRUD, while I get the data for my app in place.

So, I have Authors, and Books. A Book belongs_to an Author.

I have a huge list of books already to enter - but as I haven't entered the Authors yet - none of my books will save, as I keep getting "Trying to get property of non-object" when I save without selecting an author- despite not making Author "required".

As I haven't got my list of books organised by author (it's a straight list of titles in a CSV list) this is preventing me saving any Books.

How can I make the Author optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was more simple than I realised - I had the wrong relationship. Instead of a "belongs to" I needed a "has one". The has one relationship allows for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Within the 'rules' function of the Book model you should see something like this:

```
array('...','...','author', 'required'),
```

All you have to do is delete the 'author' property from the array, so it will no longer be required. Of course this will only work if the 'author' column in the Book table of the DB is marked as not-required.

I hope it helps you, but I'm afraid it won't solve your problem. The error message you're getting, "Trying to get property of non-object", suggests that you have another problem rather than a not-set required property in a submitted form. If it is the case, you may post the BooksController's "create" function and the  associated "_form" view in order to determine what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the thought - I'm afraid it didn't help. I don't have the author_id as a required field. If I don't set a *valid* Author id for a book, the error mentioned above appears before validation is even checked. It's something to do with the relationship, but I don't know how to get Yii to allow a "null" value in the related field.

Answer (score 0):

you could import your authors first, but this would probably wouldn't work either since your csv won't have the author_id in it

if i were you i would delete the foreign key (not the author_id field, just the fk) and import my books, then add authors and when done add the foreign key again to ensure data integrity and use it in the future

Yii won't complain if you do that

Comment: I just saw that you want to make author optional, in this case just delete the relation and you will be fine, don't even add it afterwards, go to phpmyadmin, open the table, open the relation view and remove the author_id fk

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have a list of authors to import, the name of the book normally contains the author (but in many formats so I can't programmatically work it out). There's no pk relation enforced by the db, just by Yii, so there's nothing to remove other than the Yii relationship, which destroys the rest of the app. So far I've worked around it by creating a "not set" default author, but that's far from ideal.